# Small size datasets for object detection, segmentation and localization

Tags: datasets, object-recognition, object-detection, resource-request

I am looking for a small size dataset on which I can implement object detection, object segmentation and object localization.

Can anyone suggest me a dataset less than 5GB? Or do I need to know anything before implementing these algorithms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various dataset available such as

1. Pascal VOC dataset: You can perform all your task with these. 
   [image]
   size of the dataset is as  follows
   [image]
2. ADE20K Semantic Segmentation Dataset: you can perform only segmentation here
   [image]
3. COCO dataset: This is rich dataset but a size larger then 5 GB so you can try downloading using google colab in your drive and then make a zip file of data as less than 5 GB
   [image]

You can download all these datasets using Gluoncv easily.here [link](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/api/data.datasets.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the COCO (common objects in context) dataset. 
It's often used for object detection, segmentation and localisation. 
They provide labels, and you can limit the size by downloading only a specific number of classes.
http://cocodataset.org/#explore

It's also quite a common one, so you can expect good documentation, and online answers to your questions.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

*NDDS is a UE4 plugin from NVIDIA to empower computer vision researchers to export high -quality synthetic images with metadata.
NDDS supports images, segmentation, depth, object pose, bounding box, keypoints, and custom stencils. In addition to the expo rter,
the plugin includes different components for generating highly randomized images. This randomization includes lighting, objec ts,
camera position, poses, textures, and distractors, as well as camera path following, and so forth. Together, these components allow
researchers to easily create randomized scenes for training deep neural networks*

https://github.com/yehengchen/DOPE-ROS-D435/blob/master/Synthetic-Data-UE4-DOPE.md

You can create 3D synthetic dataset here.